# Rewriting a multivariable function in python as a single variable one using sympy

Tags: python, function, sympy

```py
def cost(d,c):
    return [insert  formula]
cost=sp.lambdify([d,c],cost(d,c))
```

In the context of the problem, there is a way to write c in terms of d. I called this formula for c "rs". I am trying to change cost to a function dependent on only d with the below code.

cost=sp.lambdify(d,cost(d,rs))

However, if I were to run cost(8) or whatever, I am told

"String fallback in sympify has been deprecated since SymPy 1.6. Use
sympify(str(obj)) or sympy.core.sympify.converter or obj.*sympy*
instead. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18066 for more
info."

So what is the proper way to attack this problem?

Comment: Please provide a code example that people can run to reproduce the issue you're having. It's not at all clear from the above what you're exactly trying to achieve and how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
>>> def cost(a, b):
...   return a + b
...
>>> def rs(a):
...   return a**2
...
>>> cost_a = lambda a: cost(a, rs(a))
>>> cost_a(2)  # cost(a, rs(a)) = cost(a, a**2) = a + a**2 = a*(1 + a)
6
```